# On weak convergence of Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

Let $ X $ be a Hilbert space, $ x_n, x \in X $ and $ x_n \stackrel{w}{\to} x $, then for any $ f \in X^* $, $ f(x_n) \to f(x) $.

Now let $ f: = \Vert \cdot \Vert_X \in X^*$, we have $ \Vert x_n \Vert \to \Vert  x \Vert $.

This implies the weak convergence is equivalent to strong convergence in Hilbert space. However, it is contradicted with the right shift operator in $ l^2 $.

So where am I wrong?

Thank you for kind help in advance!

Comment: Not all norms belong to the dual, since they are not always additive ($\|x+y\|=\|x\|+\|y\|$). Is it being assumed that $\|\cdot\|_X$ is additive? They are also not always homogeneous ($\|rx\|=r\|x\|$).

Comment: @topeik no norms belong to the dual, whether additive or not.

Comment: @supinf Think about it a little. You will see that what you are saying is false. There is a very very simple example that is linear.

Comment: @topeik: I thought about it a little. I am still convinced that no norm on a Hilbert space is an element of the dual space of that Hilbert space. If you know a counterexample please let me know.  *edit*: I was wrong, apparently, see the other comments.

Comment: There is exactly one example of a norm that is linear, which is the (only) norm on $\{0\}$.

Comment: @supinf The norm in the zero space is linear. Trivial, example. Which is why I wrote my first comment in that way, so that is it strictly correct.

Comment: @supinf ok now I am convinced. thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, $f :=\|\cdot\|_X\in X^*$ is false, because it is not linear.
The elements in $X^*$ are only linear functionals.
Thus $\|x_n\|\to \|x\|$ does not follow.

Second, it should be mentioned that the convergence $\|x_n\|\to \|x\|$ is
not called strong convergence.
Strong convergence refers to the convergence $\|x_n-x\|\to 0$.
However, in Hilbert spaces the property $\|x_n\|\to \|x\|$
already implies strong convergence if $x_n$ converges weakly to $x$.

Comment: @Supint I have noticed the latter point and skip the step. The main point is that the norm is not linear. Your good answer make me get it!